# How to load WP categories into array for autocomplete?

Tags: search, forms, autocomplete

I am currently making a new site and i am stuck with the autocomplete for the standard search form from wordpress. Anyone knows how can i load my wordpress categories to use in this script?
Its a mix with javascript and php(to load my categories from wp)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what autocomplete function you are using in JS, if it is from a library or custom, but I'm assuming that it expects an array where `locations` is passed and not a string, which is what you're feeding it.

The function you should be using is `get_terms()`, not `wp_list_categories()`, the former being used for returning an array of terms in a taxonomy, the latter is for returning a string of HTML markup. You can use the `fields` argument to filter which fields you want included in the results.

Example: 
  `$locations = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'fields' => 'names'
) );`

Secondly, as mentioned above, your `locations` variable is populated with a string in JS not an array. This might be fine if the autocomplete function were to parse it as JSON automatically, but in that case your string would not be valid JSON anyway as you are outputting a `<ul>` markup string inside the brackets. Try this:

`var locations = ["<?php echo implode('", "', $locations); ?>"];`

Comment: I tried your solution but in log it gives this now : [""] (empty i guess)

Comment: Do you have any categories created in the default 'categories' taxonomy? Are you using a custom taxonomy?

Comment: Well i made custom post types and there i entered all my categories, they are the same for all cpt.

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be 'cateogry' not 'categories' for the slug

Comment: As long as it's using the same built in 'category' taxonomy, it won't matter that it's on custom post types, this will give you all terms that exist in the 'category' taxonomy regardless of post type. Now if you used custom taxonomies to create custom category taxonomies then you would need to query by those custom taxonomy slugs.

Comment: Yeah, i just found that out, thanks! The autocomplete works now but i have one more problem. I have a category " 1000 Brussel", but the autocomplete only works when i enter 1 first and not when i type Bru? Any solution?

Comment: That would depend on how your autocomplete JS function is coded, the value 1000 Brussel is in the array output by PHP, how your autocomplete relates the input to the array elements is totally dependent on it's algorithm. There are a lot of drop in auto complete solutions out there, best I can suggest is to find the one that performs best for you, may need some trial and error testing. Other option would be to write your own, but that's well beyond the scope here.

Comment: Ok, will check this out, Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, just make sure to mark this as the chosen answer since it solved the issue at hand.